# Após requisicao AJAX input não seta valor ao ManagedBean?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estou construindo um formulário de cadastro de endereço e implementei as combos referentes a Estado e Cidade respectivamente. Elas funcionam de forma habitual, com a combo da cidade sendo preenchida de acordo com o valor selecionado pela combo do estado.

Li um tutorial na internet a respeito de como implementar essa funcionalidade, entretanto estou tendo um problema bem chato no que se refere a campos obrigatórios e atribuição de valor dos inputs ao ManagedBean. Isto porque o evento ajax responsável por carregar a combo da cidade com base no valor do estado funciona, entretanto, após dar um submit no formulário de cadastro o valor da cidade não é setado no bean e o JSF cospe uma mensagem de "Campo obrigatório".

Estou a um tempo procurando a causa... mas ainda nao encontrei.

Minha implementação é a seguinte:

**endereco.xhtml**

```
<f:view>
    <p:fieldset legend="Endereco">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <p:outputLabel value="Logradouro: " id="lblLogradouro"
                    for="txtLogradouro" />
                <p:inputText value="#{enderecoBean.endereco.logradouro}"
                    id="txtLogradouro" style="width:435px;" required="true"
                    requiredMessage="É necessário preencher o campo Logradouro!" />
            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <p:outputLabel value="Numero: " id="lblNumero" for="txtNumero" />
                <p:inputText value="#{enderecoBean.endereco.numero}" id="txtNumero"
                    required="true"
                    requiredMessage="É necessário preencher o campo Número!" />
            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:panelGrid columns="4">
                <p:outputLabel value="Bairro: " id="lblBairro" for="txtBairro" />
                <p:inputText value="#{enderecoBean.endereco.bairro}" id="txtBairro"
                    required="true"
                    requiredMessage="É necessário preencher o campo Bairro!" />

                <p:outputLabel value="Complemento: " id="lblComplemento"
                    for="txtComplemento" />
                <p:inputText value="#{enderecoBean.endereco.complemento}"
                    id="txtComplemento" />
            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <p:outputLabel value="Cep " id="lblCep" for="txtCep" />
                <p:inputText value="#{enderecoBean.endereco.cep}" id="txtCep"
                    required="true"
                    requiredMessage="É necessário preencher o campo Cep!" />
            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:panelGrid columns="4">
                <p:outputLabel value="Estado: " id="lblEstado" for="estado" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="estado" value="#{enderecoBean.estadoEscolhido}"
                    converter="estadoConverter" required="true">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{enderecoBean.listaEstados}" var="e"
                        itemValue="#{e}" itemLabel="#{e.sigla}" />
                    <f:ajax render="cidade" event="change"
                        listener="#{enderecoBean.alterarCidadesPorEstado}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>

                <p:outputLabel value="Cidade: " for="cidade" id="lblCidade" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="cidade" value="#{enderecoBean.cidadeEscolhida}"
                    converter="cidadeConverter" required="true">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{enderecoBean.listaCidades}" var="c"
                        itemValue="#{c}" itemLabel="#{c.nomeCidade}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:fieldset>
</f:view>
```

**EnderecoBean.java**

```
package br.com.biblioteca.bean;

import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;
import br.com.biblioteca.dao.CidadeDAO;
import br.com.biblioteca.dao.EstadoDAO;
import br.com.biblioteca.model.Cidade;
import br.com.biblioteca.model.Endereco;
import br.com.biblioteca.model.Estado;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class EnderecoBean {

    private Endereco endereco;
    private Estado estadoEscolhido;
    private Cidade cidadeEscolhida;
    private List<Estado> listaEstados;
    private List<Cidade> listaCidades;
    private CidadeDAO cidadeDao;

    public EnderecoBean(){
        this.endereco = new Endereco();
        cidadeDao = new CidadeDAO();
        EstadoDAO dao = new EstadoDAO();
        listaEstados = dao.listar();
    }

    public void setEndereco(Endereco endereco){
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    public Endereco getEndereco(){
        return this.endereco;
    }

    public Estado getEstadoEscolhido() {
        return estadoEscolhido;
    }

    public void setEstadoEscolhido(Estado estadoEscolhido) {
        this.estadoEscolhido = estadoEscolhido;
    }

    public Cidade getCidadeEscolhida() {
        return cidadeEscolhida;
    }

    public void setCidadeEscolhida(Cidade cidadeEscolhida) {
        this.cidadeEscolhida = cidadeEscolhida;
    }

    public List<Estado> getListaEstados() {
        return listaEstados;
    }

    public void setListaEstados(List<Estado> listaEstados) {
        this.listaEstados = listaEstados;
    }

    public List<Cidade> getListaCidades() {
        return listaCidades;
    }

    public void setListaCidades(List<Cidade> listaCidades) {
        this.listaCidades = listaCidades;
    }


    public void alterarCidadesPorEstado(final AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
        if(estadoEscolhido == null)
            return;     

        try{
            this.listaCidades = cidadeDao.cidadeByEstado(estadoEscolhido);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            FacesMessage msgErro = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "ERRO","Falha ao buscar as cidades atreladas ao estado selecionado!");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msgErro);
        }
    }
}
```

**EstadoConverter.java**

```
package br.com.biblioteca.converter;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

import br.com.biblioteca.dao.EstadoDAO;
import br.com.biblioteca.model.Estado;

@FacesConverter(value="estadoConverter")
public class EstadoConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if(value != null || !value.isEmpty()){
            EstadoDAO estadoDao = new EstadoDAO();
            Estado estado = estadoDao.buscar(Integer.valueOf(value));
            return estado;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if(value instanceof Estado){
            Estado estado = (Estado)value;
            return String.valueOf(estado.getIdEstado());
        }
        return "";
    }

}
```

**CidadeConverter.java**

```
package br.com.biblioteca.converter;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

import br.com.biblioteca.dao.CidadeDAO;
import br.com.biblioteca.model.Cidade;

@FacesConverter(value = "cidadeConverter")
public class CidadeConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value != null && !value.equals("")) {
            CidadeDAO dao = new CidadeDAO();
            return dao.buscar(Integer.valueOf(value));
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value instanceof Cidade) {
            Cidade municipio = (Cidade) value;
            return String.valueOf(municipio.getIdCidade());
        }
        return "";
    }

}
```

Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso é um bug do Primefaces que pode ser corrigido facilmente colocando um elemento que envolve que o componente que será atualizado. Segue exemplo gernérico:

```
<p:selectOneMenu>
    <p:ajax update="panel-pai" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<h:panelGroup id="panel-pai">
    <p:selectOneMenu id="listaSelecao" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

Se estiver utilizando uma lista que depende de outra, não se esqueça de atualizar o próprio elemento:

```
<h:panelGroup id="panel-cidade">
    <p:selectOneMenu id="cidade">
        <p:ajax update="panel-cidade panel-estado" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</h:panelGroup>

<h:panelGroup id="panel-estado">
    <p:selectOneMenu id="estado" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

Ou então colocar ambos componentes dentro de apenas um elemento pai:

```
<h:panelGroup id="panel-endereco">
    <p:selectOneMenu id="cidade">
        <p:ajax update="panel-endereco" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>

    <p:selectOneMenu id="estado" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

Para você fazer essa atualização você deverá:

- Enviar ao seu managedBean a seleção do Estado
- Através do Estado selecionado atualizar a lista das Cidades
- Atualizará os elementos que envolvem os `selectOneMenus` correspondentes

Aplicado ao seu código:

```
<p:panelGrid id="panel-pai" columns="4">
    <p:outputLabel value="Estado: " id="lblEstado" for="estado" />
    <p:selectOneMenu id="estado" value="#{enderecoBean.estadoEscolhido}"
       converter="estadoConverter" required="true">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{enderecoBean.listaEstados}" var="e"
                       itemValue="#{e}" itemLabel="#{e.sigla}" />
        <p:ajax update="panel-pai" event="change"
           listener="#{enderecoBean.alterarCidadesPorEstado}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>

    <p:outputLabel value="Cidade: " for="cidade" id="lblCidade" />
    <p:selectOneMenu id="cidade" value="#{enderecoBean.cidadeEscolhida}"
       converter="cidadeConverter" required="true">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{enderecoBean.listaCidades}" var="c"
           itemValue="#{c}" itemLabel="#{c.nomeCidade}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</p:panelGrid>
```

- Foi colocada um `id` para o `panelGrid` que envolve seus `selectOneMenus`
- Seu `update` deverá ser em cima desse `id` que engloba os `selectOneMenus` sempre
- Recomendo mudar  `<f:ajax render="panelX"/>` para  `<p:ajax update="panelX"/>`
- Seu `h:panelGrid` pode mudar `p:panelGrid` nativo do Primefaces se preferir

Recomendo utilizar o máximo de tags nativas do Primefaces do que misturar com as tags JSTL.

---

Mais uma observação, seu managedBean deverá estar serializado. Exemplo:

```
public class EnderecoBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```